# Solved:Typo3 CacheManager not found

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I recently tried to update my Typo3 from 7.6.31 to the latest 8 LTS release and it went horribly wrong. So I decided to roll back to one of my Backups.
With 30 days of daily backup data (folders and sql file) with ervery backup i get the same error.

for example:

```
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception
Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\CacheManager' not found

Error thrown in file
/var/customers/webs/web6/old/typo3_src-7.6.27/typo3/sysext/core/Classes /Core/Bootstrap.php in line 586.

5 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap::initializeCachingFramework()


/var/customers/webs/web6/old/typo3_src-7.6.27/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Core/Bootstrap.php:

00393:             $this->disableCoreCache();
00394:         }

00395:         $this->initializeCachingFramework()

00396:             ->initializePackageManagement($packageManagerClassName)
00397:             ->initializeRuntimeActivatedPackagesFromConfiguration()


4 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap::loadConfigurationAndInitialize()


/var/customers/webs/web6/old/typo3_src-7.6.27/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Core/Bootstrap.php:

00168:     {
00169:         $this->startOutputBuffering()

00170:             ->loadConfigurationAndInitialize()

00171:             ->loadTypo3LoadedExtAndExtLocalconf(true)
00172:             ->setFinalCachingFrameworkCacheConfiguration()


3 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap::configure()


/var/customers/webs/web6/old/typo3_src-7.6.27/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Http/Application.php:

00065:         }
00066: 

00067:         $this->bootstrap->configure();

00068:     }
00069: 


2 TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Http\Application::__construct(Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader)


/var/customers/webs/web6/old/typo3_src-7.6.27/index.php:

00031: call_user_func(function () {
00032:     $classLoader = require rtrim(realpath(__DIR__ . '/typo3'), '\\/') . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

00033:     (new \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Http\Application($classLoader))->run();

00034: });


1 {closure}()


/var/customers/webs/web6/old/typo3_src-7.6.27/index.php:

00032:     $classLoader = require rtrim(realpath(__DIR__ . '/typo3'), '\\/') . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
00033:     (new \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Http\Application($classLoader))->run();

00034: });
```

What i tried so far: 
delete all files in Typo3temp, tried different days of backup data, seach the webs.....
It looks like no one has a similar problem.

Comment: Your errors are from typo3_src-7.6.27. Try TYPO3 7.6.31 as you wrote. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Yes, actually ist did help, somehow....I just linked a fresh downloaded source, rather than the one from my backups.... now it works !

Comment: OK. I write it as a answer. Please mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using latest TYPO3 CMS 7.6.31 solve it.